# How to get the stored procedures that get executed to print in the output

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I recently learned that SET STATISTICS IO ON shows what tables get referenced and a lot of useful information.
Currently, I'm debugging a stored procedure that branches out and calls a bunch of other stored procedures during the process.

So, my question is: Is there a mechanism similar to STATISTICS IO, which prints out the tables used, that prints out which stored procedures get executed?
If so, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you simply want to show dependencies where the object type is a Stored Procedure.

[Different way to find SQL Dependencies](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2999/different-ways-to-find-sql-server-object-dependencies/)

Comment: Wow, I found that super helpful!  Thanks for sharing that.  Is there also a way to print the name of the stored procedures that actually get executed in a particular run?

Comment: If you use the [OBJECT_NAME() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186301.aspx) you can get the object name. If the stored procedures are chained then you can use one of the examples in the original link. if they are in the same SP, i'm just having a look.

Comment: The stored procedure I'm looking at is the type that looks at a parameter, and depending on that value, calls one or more of many other stored procedures--which may also do more of the same.  So, for me, it would be really great to see which stored procedures actually got executed.

Answer (score 2):

If you open up [SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx), and run the Stored Procedure, you can get a trace of the nested SP calls.  If you've not used it before, do check it out.

Comment: I generally do this, and I agree, this would normally be my preferred way of doing things.  However, the bug I'm looking at is in our production environment and I don't have rights to run SQL profiler in production.